# I can't access a method in a class

Tags: java, arrays, methods

This is my first attempt creating array of objects in Java.
my code is a hot mess and full of stupid beginners mistakes.

```
package javaapplication62;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class JavaApplication62 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        while (true) {

            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("1.Enroll Student");
            System.out.println("2.Offer Course");

            String name = in.next();
            int choice = in.nextInt();

            if (choice == 1) {

                student_class[] studentList = new student_class[500];

                studentList[0] = new student_class();

                while (true) {

                    System.out.print(" Enter name of the student: ");
                    studentList[0].setName(in.next());

                    System.out.println("");
                    System.out.print(" The student is given the unique ID =  " + studentList[0].getUniqueStudentID() + " and the number of students =  " + studentList[0].getNumberOfStudents());

                    System.out.print("> and the number of students :  ");
                    studentList[0].setnumberOfStudents(in.nextInt);

                    System.out.println("");
                    System.out.print(" Enter the e-mail address of the student: ");
                    studentList[0].setemail(in.next);

                    System.out.print("Enter the semester number of the student:  ");
                    studentList[0].setsemesterNumber(in.nextInt);

                    System.out.print(" Add another student (Y/N): ");
                    char add = in.next().charAt(0);
                    if (add == 'Y' || add == 'y') {

                    }

                    if (add == 'N' || add == 'n') {
                        break;
                    }

                }

            } else if (choice == 2) {

                while (true) {

                    Course[] courseOfferedList;
                    courseOfferedList = new Course[500];
                    courseOfferedList[0] = new Course();

                    System.out.println("Enter the course code : ");
                    courseOfferedList[0].setCourseCode(in.next());

                    System.out.println(" Enter the course title: ");
                    courseOfferedList[0].setCourseTitl(in.next());

                    System.out.println(" Enter the credit hours of the course: ");
                    courseOfferedList[0].setCreditHours(in.nextInt());

                    System.out.print(" Add another course (Y/N): ");
                    char add2 = in.next().charAt(0);
                    if (add2 == 'Y' || add2 == 'y') {
                    }

                    if (add2 == 'N' || add2 == 'n') {
                        break;
                    }

                }

            }

        }
    }

}
```

**The Student Class.**

```
    public class student_class {
    private String name;
    private int uniqueStudentID;
    private String email;
    private int mobileNumber;
    private int semesterNumber;
    static int numberOfStudents = 0;

    public student_class() {

        name = null;
        uniqueStudentID = 0;
        email = null;
        mobileNumber = 0;
        semesterNumber = 0;
        numberOfStudents++;

    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setUniqueStudentID(int uniqueStudentID) {
        this.uniqueStudentID = uniqueStudentID;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public void setMobileNumber(int mobileNumber) {
        this.mobileNumber = mobileNumber;
    }

    public void setSemesterNumber(int semesterNumber) {
        this.semesterNumber = semesterNumber;
    }

    public void setNumberOfStudents(int numberOfStudents) {
        this.numberOfStudents = numberOfStudents;
    }

    public String getName() {

        return name;
    }

    public int getUniqueStudentID() {

        return uniqueStudentID;

    }

    public String getEmail() {

        return email;

    }

    public int getMobileNumber() {

        return mobileNumber;
    }

    public int getSemesterNumber() {

        return semesterNumber;
    }

    public int getNumberOfStudents() {

        return numberOfStudents;
    }

    void setName() {

    }

    void setuniqueStudentID() {

    }

    void setnumberOfStudents() {

    }

    void setsemesterNumber() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    void setmobileNumber() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    void setemail() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

}
```

**The Course class:**

```
public class Course {

    private int courseCode;
    private String courseTitl;
    private int creditHours;
    static int numberOfCourses = 0;

    public int getCourseCode() {
        return courseCode;
    }

    public void setCourseCode(int courseCode) {
        this.courseCode = courseCode;
    }

    public String getCourseTitl() {
        return courseTitl;
    }

    public void setCourseTitl(String courseTitl) {
        this.courseTitl = courseTitl;
    }

    public int getCreditHours() {
        return creditHours;
    }

    public void setCreditHours(int creditHours) {
        this.creditHours = creditHours;
    }

    public static int getNumberOfCourses() {
        return numberOfCourses;
    }

    public static void setNumberOfCourses(int numberOfCourses) {
        Course.numberOfCourses = numberOfCourses;   
}}
```

Everytime I run it this error shows up :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported yet.
    at javaapplication62.student_class.setName(student_class.java:11)
    at javaapplication62.JavaApplication62.main(JavaApplication62.java:29)
Java Result:
```

This is how I want the output

> is used for input and < is used for output

```
{Display the menu, Choose the menu item}
> 1

> Enter name of the student: john

< The student is given the unique ID = 1 and the number of students = 1

> Enter the e-mail address of the student: john@stu.fau.edu.uk

> Enter the semester number of the student:  3

> Add another student (Y/N): Y

> Enter name of the student: Ibrahim

< The student is given the unique ID = 2 and the number of students = 2

> Enter the e-mail address of the student:  Ibrahim@stu.fau.edu.uk

> Enter the semester number of the student:  3
> Add another student (Y/N): N

{Display the menu, Choose the menu item}
> 2

> Enter the course code: CPCS203

> Enter the course title: Programming 2

> Enter the credit hours of the course: 4
> Add another course (Y/N): Y

> Enter the course code: CPCS204

> Enter the course title: Data Structures

> Enter the credit hours of the course: 3
> Add another course (Y/N): N

{Display the menu, Choose the menu item}
```

Comment: The error is coming from a method which doesn't throw any exceptions according to the code you posted. Are you sure you're running your most updated code?

Comment: _"my code is a hot mess..."_ -- If you know this, stop now and refactor it so it's not a hot mess.  You will probably find a number of errors while doing this.

Comment: The error says it's being thrown from `student_class.setName()` but that method does not contain a `throw` statement in the code you show.  Clearly the code you show is not the code that is running and producing the error, so you will need to get things sync'ed up before anybody here can help you.

Comment: sorry but l'm new to this. I know my code is bad but I dont know why its bad. I tried to delete the throw statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of your errors are in `JavaApplication62` class. Ive corrected them to get the desired output you want. There are still many problems with all your classes. I'll Leave that up to you to rectify.

Look to the comments for the corrections.

```
/**
 * Created by Ninan John J P on 6/30/2016.
 */
import java.util.Scanner;

public class JavaApplication62 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        while (true) {

            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("1.Enroll Student");
            System.out.println("2.Offer Course");

            //String name = in.next(); Not required. This will want a text input before proceeding further.
            int choice = in.nextInt();

            if (choice == 1) {

                student_class[] studentList = new student_class[500];

                studentList[0] = new student_class();

                while (true) {

                    System.out.print(" Enter name of the student: ");
                    studentList[0].setName(in.next());

                    System.out.println("");
                    System.out.print(" The student is given the unique ID =  " + studentList[0].getUniqueStudentID() + " and the number of students =  " + studentList[0].getNumberOfStudents());

                   /* System.out.print("> and the number of students :  ");
                    //studentList[0].setnumberOfStudents(in.nextInt);
                    studentList[0].setNumberOfStudents(in.nextInt());
                   */ //This is not required. You have already done this in the previous print statment.

                    System.out.println("");
                    System.out.print(" Enter the e-mail address of the student: ");
                    //studentList[0].setemail(in.next); you are calling the wrong method. Also in.next should be a method.
                    studentList[0].setEmail(in.next());

                    System.out.print("Enter the semester number of the student:  ");
                   // studentList[0].setsemesterNumber(in.nextInt); // same as prev error

                    studentList[0].setSemesterNumber(in.nextInt());

                    System.out.print(" Add another student (Y/N): ");
                    char add = in.next().charAt(0);
                    if (add == 'Y' || add == 'y') {

                    }

                    if (add == 'N' || add == 'n') {
                        break;
                    }

                }

            } else if (choice == 2) {

                while (true) {

                    Course[] courseOfferedList;
                    courseOfferedList = new Course[500];
                    courseOfferedList[0] = new Course();

                    System.out.println("Enter the course code : ");
                    //courseOfferedList[0].setCourseCode(in.next()); // next() returns a string. You need nextInt() here.   

                    courseOfferedList[0].setCourseCode(in.nextInt());

                    System.out.println(" Enter the course title: ");
                    courseOfferedList[0].setCourseTitl(in.next());

                    System.out.println(" Enter the credit hours of the course: ");
                    courseOfferedList[0].setCreditHours(in.nextInt());

                    System.out.print(" Add another course (Y/N): ");
                    char add2 = in.next().charAt(0);

//                    if (add2 == 'Y' || add2 == 'y') { // not needed
//                    }

                    if (add2 == 'N' || add2 == 'n') {
                        break;
                    }

                }

            }

        }
    }

}
```

Also I've not improved your indentation. You should look at that also.

This will give you the output you mentioned in the question. But I think you should refactor a lot of your code altogether.

Comment: thank you. I will try what you mention